# rotate div with css constantly - just css

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to rotate  div with css constantly? how can i do it?

for example:

```
div {
   width:100px;
   height:100px;
   border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

using CSS3 @keyframes Rule

```
//html
 <div class="rotating"></div>



//css

div {
width:100px;
height:100px;
border: 1px solid red;
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotating {
    from{
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    to{
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}

.rotating {
    -webkit-animation: rotating 2s linear infinite;
}
```

here is the example
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GopMeq